# How do I increment value by 1 until a certain point inside a while loop (Pseudocode)?

Tags: increment, pseudocode

What I have to do is make a game in which the user is given 10 tries to try and guess my preferred number. They have 10 tries to guess it.

I have done all the code however i need to know how I would increment the number of tries by 1 until 10 inside the while loop that I have used.

Please explain using Pseudocode.

Thanks.

Comment: SO isn’t a service to do your homework - please check here [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: nonetheless - SO isn't here to do your homework - or answer your exam questions for you. if you want to get assistance from the community you need to show the effort that you have made, as well as what is not working - and what your expectations are.

Comment: My question is a simple question, I dont need to go into depth with what my question is since its written in Pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to pseudo javascript:

```
let maxWrongTries = 5;
let numberOfWrongTries = 0;

someButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if( !anwserIsCorrect(event.target.value) ){
        numberOfWrongTries += 1;
    }

    if( numberOfWrongTries >= maxWrongTries){
        // Do something when there are too many tries, like remove the form
        // or display a message
    }
});
```

How to check if an answer is right, and what to do when the max tries is reached is up to you. Also: You might want to reset the counter to 0 when an answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

You would have a counter to count the number of tries. Each loop iteration you increase the count by 1. Look if the counter is larger at your target in the while loop to stop the loop when done.

Something like this:

```
numTries = 0

while numTries < 10

    *do game stuff*

    numTries = numTries + 1

* handle end of game *
```